# Where can I can find a UTM 10 x 10 km grid?

Tags: data, utm, portugal

I am looking for a UTM 10x10km grid map for Portugal and I can’t find it. Does somebody know where I can find this shapefile?

Comment: How about the world : http://giswiki.org/wiki/UTM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it on your own using SAGA GIS
http://marinedataliteracy.org/margis/grats_frames.htm here do you have a quick tutor
Or try 'Vector Grid' tool (under Vector > Research Tools) in Qgis